# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector on Jetty

Tags: linux, embedded-jetty

I have a java web app that uses Jetty embedded and when I try to run in a linux environment I have the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Connector
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at br.com.teste.install.Launcher.work(Launcher.java:23)
at br.com.teste.install.Install.main(Install.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 4 more
```

When I run exactly the same app in a windows environment this works without any error.

I have no ideia for what happen this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Unless you post your startup script(s) and anvironment, I don't think you'll get any sort of help.